# paperjs: Why doesn't the onFrame event work when it is inside onKeyDown event?

Tags: javascript, events, paperjs

```
<script type="text/paperscript" canvas="paper"> 
    function onKeyDown(event) { 
        alert('key pressed');          
        function onFrame(event) { 
            console.log('frames running'); 
        }
    }   
</script>
```

The following code works but the above doesn't. Why doesn't the onFrame event trigger when it's used as a statement?

```
function onKeyDown(event) { 
    alert('key pressed');          
    view.onFrame = function(event) { //This line is makes a difference
        console.log('frames running'); 
    }
}
```

Also, in the below code if I use the view.onFrame method, the circle scales down but stops abruptly when another key is pressed.

```
function onKeyDown(event) {
    var circle = new Path.Circle((view.size * Point.random()), 50);
    circle.fillColor = 'purple';
    view.onFrame = function(event) {
        circle.scale(.9);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, late to the party 'cause I've the same question as the last part of your post but I figured it out.

On your last code, use `circle.onFrame` instead of `view.onFrame` so that the created circle continues to animate and you can still create new circles after every `onKeyDown` event.

As for the first part, I am not sure why but I tried it first too before finding your question, so thanks.